# Amplifying a minuscule signal without external power source?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, audio

I recently came across this circuit :

http://sgitornado.altervista.org/diyirig.html

[image: guitar to jack circuit]

I tried to understand it, but I have several questions I can't really search for, as I'm an amateur and don't know the terms or what I am looking at exactly.

1. I don't understand why the circuit starts with such a small capacitor; doesn't this mess with the signal as it is output by the guitar?
2. Why are there so many resistors and capacitors in parallel, are these values just magic numbers or can we calculate them?
3. The point of the transistor is to amplify the guitar mic pickup signal, but are the 10mV output really powering this? This particularly bothers me as this value sounds way too small for anything.

Comment: Of course it does have an external power supply; the mic input on the headphone jack provides power.

Comment: Power must come in through the ferrite bead (which helps filter out unwanted noise), note that the jack is a TRRS type with four contacts. This looks similar to a common-source amplifier configuration (similar to a common-emitter amplifier, but with a FET instead of an NPN transistor). None of the resistors are connected in parallel, but what puzzles me is I would expect the 4.7kohm resistor to be in series with the drain, and a series capacitor to pass through the amplified signal to the output -- I don't see a voltage output, so maybe it's current output instead of voltage output?

Comment: @BrianDrummond ahhhh you mean it should be read right to left? I expected the 3.5mm jack's microphone to only be an input

Comment: @MarkU oh thank you! "common source amplifier" is the word.

Comment: @MarkU ... to switch a phone to use its external microphone you need to load that mic input with something like 1.6 kilohms to GND. That 4K7 forms part of that load. The output IS current; converted to voltage by a resistance to +V (which also supplies the power) inside the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The size of the input capacitor depends on the load following it.  In this case, that's the 39kohm resistor.  The capacitor and the resistor together form a high pass filter.  It's mostly there to keep DC out of the amplifier - it would mess with the gate bias on the FET.  In this case, the cutoff frequency is around 200 Hz. It is **not** a steep (sharp) filter - the lower frequencies will still get through, they'll be attenuated (weakened) just a little bit.  DC is blocked entirely.  Look up "RC high pass filter" for information on calculating the values.
2. Each of the resistors and capacitors has a job - they are not magic numbers.  I can't tell you how to calculate some of them, while I understand some of the others.  Take that 10pF capacitor.  It is there to get rid of radio frequency signals - you don't want your cellphone signal blasting through your guitar amplifier.  The 10pF works to together with the 39k resistor to form a low pass filter. It is intended to filter out frequencies above about 400kHz.  The 1.2k and the 4.7k resistors work together to bias the FET into a place where it operate linearly - I know what they are for, but I can't tell you how to calculate them. I'm not sure what the 470pF is doing - probably has more to do with filtering out RF.
3. The power comes from the connector that goes to the PC or cellphone.  PCs and cellphones expect you to connect an electret microphone to them.  Typical electret microphones have a tiny amplifier inside them, and so need a little bit of DC to operate.  The microphone input accepts AC, but puts out DC for the electret microphone.  This circuit mimics the behavior of a normal electret microphone - it takes in DC (from the phone or PC) and gives out AC (back to the phone or PC.)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The TRRS plug goes into a computer or mobile phone headset connector. They provide power to this circuit, just like they power the similar looking circuits inside the headset microphones. This just has a guitar connector instead of the charged mic diaphragm.

The component values are also not magic, we are just not presented with the decisions how they are calculated, but it all boils down to what impedance on amplifier input the guitar is capable of driving, how much amplification is wanted, and what kind of impedance input the amplifier must drive.